# How to iterate over a nested list to assign function parameters?

Tags: python, list, function

What I'm trying to do is loop through list of tuples "years" to assign (yS1, yE1), (yS2, yE2) etc. to call portfolio(x,y) for as many "year start" and "year end" as I have in my list "years".

```
yS1 = '2013-01-01'
yE1 = '2015-01-01'

yS2 = '2015-01-01'
yE2 = '2017-01-01'

yS3 = '2017-01-01'
yE3 = '2019-01-01'

yS4 = '2019-01-01'
yE4 = '2021-01-01'

years = [(yS1,yE1),(yS2,yE2),(yS3,yE3),(yS4,yE4)]

def portfolio(yearS,yearE):
```

```
for x in years:
      portfolio(x)
```

this code results in the following:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-003ce9caf9f8> in <module>
     53 
     54 for x in years:
---> 55     portfolio(x)

TypeError: portfolio() missing 1 required positional argument: 'yearE'
```

What can I do? I have tried using [] instead of () inside my list too. My reasoning is that this loop should result in `portfolio(yS1,yE1)` and so forth.

Comment: Try `portfolio(x[0],x[1])`

Comment: Or `portfolio(*x)`

Comment: lol. amazing thank you! No idea how that slipped past me.

Comment: Or `for x, y in years: portfolio(x, y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good fit for destructing, perhaps also give x and y good names for what they contain, e.g. "start_date", "end_date".

```py
arr = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

def portfolio(yearS, yearE):
    pass

for start_date, end_date in arr:
    portfolio(start_date, end_date)
```

I find this clearer then using splat operator (*) or indexing the tuple ([0] etc)